# filename too long error windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, filenames

OK, I need some super help please on 2 things:

1. Trying to rename a folder on my desktop from "New Folder" to VBA I am getting an error stating the the folder or destination name would be to long etc.
2. Which I feel may be related, I am trying to install Command and Conquer Red Alert 1 from origin's ultimate 17 year collection and getting an error say westwoodchat.msi was not installed correctly setup cannot continue (1603). I have tried installing the package separately but get the same error when trying to install as above I have been round in circles with both ea and Microsoft getting very very frustrated please if you know the solution to these problems please let me know I will thank you and inform you if the steps provided have already been test I am going to attach my dx diag so you get all the info you need on my system.

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
Time of this report: 9/30/2014, 13:21:16
       Machine name: D1-PC
   Operating System: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_gdr.140303-2144)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: BIOSTAR Group
       System Model: N61PB-M2S
               BIOS: )Phoenix - Award WorkstationBIOS v6.00PG
          Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 630 Processor (4 CPUs), ~2.8GHz
             Memory: 4096MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 4094MB RAM
          Page File: 1846MB used, 6340MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 64bit Unicode

------------
DxDiag Notes
------------
```

Comment: the whole Path, it is possible to get an error of a similar nature when the whole interleaved folder under folder in folder path is too long. for simplicity try to keep the whole (path and file name) under 255 and see how that goes?

Comment: I have checked rechecked and checked again this is not the real issue

Comment: Can you post us the complete path from start to finish for both the source and destination? You may replace your username with the same amount of "x" for characters and spaces. For example: `C:\users\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\desktop\my folder\my subfolder\ New Folder` to `C:\users\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\desktop\my folder\my subfolder\VBA`

Comment: C:\Users\d1\Desktop\New Folder to c:\Users\d1\Desktop\VBA

I should also note I am able to change the names of applications on the desktop

Comment: @LPChip C:\Users\d1\Desktop\New Folder to c:\Users\d1\Desktop\VBA I should also note I am able to change the names of applications on the desktop

Comment: Run `CHKDSK` and ensure you have no disk/file-system corruption.  Try renaming the folder via the command prompt to see if it behaves any differently (ie: different error message).

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Both have been attempted same problem and no errors

Comment: And CHKDSK came up clean?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes all clean

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Retried with CMD seems to have worked buyt doesn't solve the issue of the installation